# npm npm run watch-poll error for homestead

Tags: node.js, npm, homestead

I am trying to use npm for a project I am working on in Homestead however I am getting some errors.
I ran

`npm run watch-poll`

but I get this error

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/testlaravel$ npm run watch-poll

> @ watch-poll /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel
> npm run watch -- --watch-poll


> @ watch /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel
> npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"


> @ development /home/vagrant/code/testlaravel
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress 
--hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"

sh: 1: cross-env: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ development: "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll""

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-18T14_11_57_194Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: "npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll""
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-18T14_11_57_246Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch-poll: "npm run watch -- --watch-poll"
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-18T14_11_57_290Z-debug.log
```

I'm new to npm and I have no idea what to do and I have not found anyone online with a similar problem.

npm version = 6.7.0

node version = v10.15.1

If you need it.

I would appreciate any help, also if you need anymore info about what i'm running and how things are set up let me know.

**edit 1**

running

```
npm install
```

gives this result

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/testlaravel$ npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/testlaravel/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist/package.json.3101396508'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 11757 packages in 87.877s
found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

**edit 2**

Ok so I ran

```
sudo npm i -g cross-env
```

because I got a permissions error without the sudo bit, and it looks like it worked.

However I am getting a new error now

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                  3:18:10 PM

 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

I guess this is a problem with the my code/framework (i'm using laravel) but yes `sudo npm i -g cross-env` looks like it fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing module cross-env. Run:

```
npm i -g cross-env
```

to install cross-env globally.

Comment: doing it with `sudo` helped me to solve my problem.